# Is my proof of $\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} n^3\cdot i^2 = \frac{1}{3}$ correct?

Tags: integration, functions, proof-verification

I wanted to prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} n^3\cdot i^2 = \frac{1}{3}$ without using the identity $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1}{6}$. I did it as follows:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} n^3\cdot i^2$

$= \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} n^3 \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} i^2$

$= \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} n^3 \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} i\cdot(\frac{2}{n}-2i+1)$

$= \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} n^3\sum_{i=1}^{1/n} \frac{2i}{n}-2i^2+i$

$= \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} n^3 (\sum_{i=1}^{1/n}(\frac{2i}{n})-\sum_{i=1}^{1/n} (2i^2)+\sum_{i=1}^{1/n} (i))$

$= \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} n^3(\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{1/n} (i)+\sum_{i=1}^{1/n} (i) - \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} (2i^2))$

$= \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} n^3(\frac{2+n}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{1/n}(i) - \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} (2i^2))$

$= \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} n^3(\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2n^3}-\sum_{i=1}^{1/n} 2i^2)$

$= \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}-2n^3\sum_{i=1}^{1/n} i^2$

$= \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} 1 -2n^3\sum_{i=1}^{1/n}i^2$

$\Longrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} 1 -2n^3\sum_{i=1}^{1/n}i^2 = \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} n^3 \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} i^2$

$\Longrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} 1 -2n^3\sum_{i=1}^{1/n}i^2 - \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} n^3 \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} i^2 = 0$

$\Longrightarrow 1 - 2\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} n^3 \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} i^2 = \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} n^3 \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} i^2$

$\Longrightarrow 1 - 3\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} n^3 \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} i^2 = 0$

$\Longrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} n^3 \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} i^2 = \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^{1/n} n^3\cdot i^2 = \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Where did that $(\frac{2}{n}-2i+1)$ come from?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ This identity can be proved via induction. If I add all square numbers from 1 to t (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 ... + t^2), I'm basically adding sums of uneven numbers (1^2 = 1, 2^2 = 1+3, 3^2 = 1+3+5, ..., t^2 = 1+3+5...+(2t-1). Using this equation, we can see that 1^2+2^2...+t^2 = 1+(1+3)+(1+3+5)+...+(1+3+5+...+(2t-1)) = 1*(2t-1)+2*(2t-3)+3*(2t-5)+...+t*1. With t = 1/n, we get the identity I used in my proof.

Comment: I don't doubt that. But if I was marking the proof, there would be a red mark there (proof of the used equality missing).

Answer (score 2):

A better approach, and probably the approach you were supposed to follow, without using the formulae $\sum_{i=1}^ni^k$ for $k=1,2$ is to use the definition of the Riemann integral as follows:

Set $t=\lfloor \frac{1}{n}\rfloor$.

Divide $[0,1]$ into $t$ sections of length $\frac{1}{t}$.

Note that $n\to 0$ is the same as $t \to \infty$

Using Riemann's formula:
$$\int_0^1 f(x) dx=\lim_{t\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^t f(0+i\Delta x)\Delta x$$

Take $f(x)=x^2$. Note that $\Delta x = \frac{1-0}{t}=n$

$$\int_0^1 x^2 dx=\lim_{t\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^t (i^2n^2)\cdot n$$

$$\frac{1}{3}=\int_0^1 x^2 dx=\lim_{t\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^t i^2n^3$$

Comment: Why the downvote? What part of this is wrong? lol  The question does have the "integration" tag. Therefore, I'm allowed to use Riemann's definition of integral for sure.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the answer. Perhaps because you didn't include if the OP's solution is correct or not.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: I tried to understand the OP's answer, but there are many things about his answer that are not clear to me. Instead, I left him a comment first, but then I realized I could show him a better approach. I believe if this was an exercise in a book or in a problem set, they probably wanted to test the OP's understanding of the definition of the Riemann integral.

Comment: Two downvotes for a perfectly clear and good answer and none of the people who downvoted has the courtesy to leave a comment and express their reason at least.